# Batch file - matching file extensions

Tags: regex, batch-file, file-extension

Probably far too easy question, but how do I match a file extension such as `.jpg` while not matching `jpg~` (i.e. a jpg that a program has made a local copy of?) My current line is:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.jpg') do echo %%~na
```

But if any program has a copy of one of the files open (and thus has made a `.jpg~` file) this regexp will match those too. I found a reference to `$` being the 'end of line', but doing this doesn't work at all:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.jpg$') do echo %%~na
```

Comment: The `$` meaning end of the line is from regular expressions. It's definitely not part of simple wildcard matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to filter this with just a FOR command (unless you pipe the output of dir to findstr) but in this case, adding a simple if test is all that is needed:

```
for %%A IN (*.jpg) DO if "%%~xA"==".jpg" @echo %%~A
```

Comment: This IMHO retarded behavior is confirmed by http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=164351

Comment: Updated KB link: https://web.archive.org/web/20040625205217/http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=164351

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem arises from the short-name representation. (Use `dir /X` and you can see that `xxx.jpg` and `xxx.jpg~` both have a 8.3 file-name that ends with `.jpg`.)

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. So despite the fact that dir is using the /b option, it still matches on the 8.3 filenames? Oh, Windows...

Comment: @Stephen: Why should `/b` change how file names are matched? If just controls how the results are output.

Comment: Well, it entirely depends on how they implemented the matching, but I would have thought that if one knew the user wanted the output in full non-8.3 format, they'd match on the full name. Then again, I don't know how much, if any, the language changed after non-8.3 names came out.